# Why does joining two datasets and applying filter cause "error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type"?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am joining two datasets - first one coming from stream and second one which is in HDFS.

I am using scala in spark. After joining the two datasets , I need to apply filter on the joined datasets, but here I am facing as issue. Please assist to resolve.

I am using the code below,

```
 val streamkv = streamrecs.map(_.split("~")).map(r => ( r(0), (r(5), r(6)))) 
val HDFSlines = sc.textFile("/user/Rest/sample.dat").map(_.split("~")).map(r => ( r(1), (r(0) r(3),r(4),))) 
val streamwindow = streamkv.window(Minutes(1)) 

val join1 = streamwindow.transform(joinRDD => { joinRDD.join(HDFSlines)} )
```

I am getting the following error, when I use the filter

```
val tofilter = join1.filter {
     | case (r(0), (r(5), r(6)),(r(0),r(3),r(4))) =>
     | r(4).contains("iPhone")
     | }.count()
<console>:48: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2, T3)
required: (String, ((String, String), (String, String, String)))
       case (r(0), (r(5), r(6)),(r(0),r(3),r(4))) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

In scala (which is a typed language FYI), the pattern matching (*case*) allows to *'extract'* variables in your block for local usage. Therefore

```
case (r(0), (r(5), r(6)),(r(0),r(3),r(4))) =>
```

is illegal, cause you're not calling r functions here, but extracting the values (think function declaration).

Assuming the objects in your resulting stream/collection join1 follows this type signature `(_, (_, _), (_, _, String))`, you should try :

```
val tofilter = join1.filter {
 | case (_, (_, _),(_,_,device)) =>
 | device.contains("iPhone")
 | }.count()
```

Comment: I tried this, but still facing error. Can you suggest?                                                                     `scala> val tofilter = join1.filter {
     | case (_, (_, _),(_,_,device)) =>
     | device.contains("iPhone")'
     | }
<console>:50: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2, T3)
required: (String, ((String, String), (String, String, String)))
       case (_, (_, _),(_,_,device)) =>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is a missing pair of round brackets.

The line with `case (r(0), (r(5), r(6)),(r(0),r(3),r(4)))` should rather be `case (_, ((_, _),(_,_,device))) =>` - note the brackets around the last two elements - `Tuple2` and `Tuple3` objects.